# WooCommerce cadastro

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Olá, estou fazendo um projeto de uma loja online utilizando Wordpress + WooCommerce.

O problema é o seguinte, na página de Checkout, por padrão o woocommerce adiciona vários campos de preenchimento, como: Informações de cadastro, cadastro de endereço de cobrança, endereço de entrega e informações de pagamento.

Gostaria de saber se alguém sabe como remover o cadastro de cliente do checkout e fazer uma página somente para isso, por exemplo, ao invés do cliente sair do carrinho e cair na página de Checkout direto, ele segue os seguintes passos:

Carrinho > Página de login/cadastro > Checkout (referência Dafiti)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assim, seria adicionada uma nova página onde o cliente possa efetuar o login ou realizar cadastro antes de chegar ao Checkout, que agora exigiria menos campos de preenchimento e ficaria menos confuso com tantos elementos na mesma tela.

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro utilizar o plugin [WooCommerce Checkout Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-checkout-manager/), com ele você pode remover campos desnecessários e ele possui diversas funcionalidades para personalização da pagina de checkout.

Answer (score 1):

O WooCommerce já tem essa opção.

1. Desabilitar o checkout de visitante. Assim quando um usuário não logado for finalizar a compra, o WooCommerce vai solicitar o login.

WooCommerce -> Configurações -> Finalizar Compra

Desmarque a opção - Ativar finalização como visitante

2. Desabilitar o cadastro no checkout. Se você quiser um modelo parecido com a tela que mandou na pergunta, precisa desabilitar o cadastro no checkout, senão o usuário não logado vai poder preencher os dados e fazer um cadastro na página de checkou. É uma boa opção em termos de usabilidade, mas se você quer que ele clique em outro link para ir pra página de cadastro:

WooCommerce -> Configurações -> Conta

Desmarque a opção - Habilitar registro na página de "Finalizar compra"